# Can't understand this kanji use in my song lyrics

Tags: kanji

I know this is probably a stupid question, but 嫌だ was in a song I was listening too. Is this incorrect usage? I know 嫌い means hateful but you don't drop the い to add だ do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, 嫌 is not used as the adjective 嫌｛きら｝い but as an adjective, 嫌｛いや｝な. See for example [weblio](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E5%AB%8C%E3%81%AA). Furthermore, 嫌{いや}だ is pretty much a [set phrase](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E5%AB%8C%E3%81%A0), meaning both:

- Unpleasantness, discomfort
- To refuse / to avoid

And by the way, 嫌{きら}い as hateful is not the most common sense. My dictionary lists:

- Dislike, hate, suspicion
- Dislike, hatred, fear